# create username and password for monogdb in PuPHPet

Tags: mongodb, puppet, centos6, puphpet

I am using PuPHPet(https://puphpet.com/) for my local development. I have centos65-x64, mongodb version 2.6.3 installed. PuPHPet does not have any options for setup username and password for mongodb. But the mongodb model they using it has example for setup username and password:

```
mongodb_user { testuser:
  ensure        => present,
  password_hash => mongodb_password('testuser', 'p@ssw0rd'),
  database      => testdb,
  roles         => ['readWrite', 'dbAdmin'],
  tries         => 10,
  require       => Class['mongodb::server'],
}
```

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mongodb
I added those code in manifest.pp and vagrant reload --provision. I am getting this error: 
****not authorized on testdb to execute command****. I was also trying add root user. like this:

```
mongodb_user { admin:
  ensure        => present,
  password_hash => mongodb_password('admin', 'adminpass'),
  database      => admin,
  roles         => ['root'],
  tries         => 10,
  require       => Class['mongodb::server'],
}
```

it also gave me the same error: **not authorized on admin to execute command**. I have no idea how to add username and password. I can manually add username and password after i did **vagrant ssh** but i think thats not the purpose of using vagrnat and puppet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the `admin` and `testdb` databases exist?

Comment: admin db exists by default but test does not need exits. it will create if not exits

Answer (score 0):

make sure you start mongo without --auth. Then you can create an admin user as described here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/. Then start up again with --auth, and use the admin user to add new users. I haven`t managed myself to create an old school root user (using the built-in "root" role), the root role actually needs to authenticate on the db he is first added to (thus you need to add him to test db using the admin user).